# TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

When running with Angular, I'm getting thje error `TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.` for [Javascript getters and setters in this Abstract Typescript class](https://github.com/fireflysemantics/slice/blob/master/src/AbstractStore.ts).

This is the source:

```
  /**
   * The current id key for the EStore instance.
   * @return this.config.idKey;
   */
  get ID_KEY(): string {
    return this.config.idKey
  }
  /**
   * The current guid key for the EStore instance.
   * @return this.config.guidKey;
   */
  get GUID_KEY(): string {
    return this.config.guidKey
  }
```

This was working fine until the most recent version of Angular.  Are we no longer allowed to use getters and setters in Abstract classes?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This isn't an Angular error.

TypeScript 3.7 introduced a breaking change for getters and setters in the type definition files.

> As mentioned above, TypeScript 3.7 emits get/set accessors in .d.ts files which can cause breaking changes for consumers on older versions of TypeScript like 3.5 and prior. TypeScript 3.6 users will not be impacted, since that version was future-proofed for this feature.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#class-field-mitigations

You should be using TypeScript 3.6 or higher if you're going to consume type definitions generated with 3.7 or higher.

Comment: OK so I need to make sure Angular is using the latest version of Typescript?

Comment: @Ole it depends which version of Angular you're running, because you can only upgrade to the highest version supported by that version of Angular. It's possible to disable the TypeScript version restriction on Angular, but I can not say if that is a stable thing to do.

Comment: Ah - I tried bumping Typescript only, and Angular wants it kept between versions 3.4.0 and 3.6.0.  Do you know if theres a command we can run to update everything in one snap?

Comment: @Ole it depends what version of Angular you are running, but the Angular CLI now has an upgrade tool. I'd make sure you can rollback changes before you do any upgrade. https://angular.io/cli/update

Answer (score 0):

I had this a similar problem with google-auth-library.

I'm on Ubuntu and call tsc to transpile my nodejs server from typescript to javascript, but running 'tsc' was throwing the 'TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context' error.

Initially, I tried updating typescript by running npm install typescript@latest from my server directory but was still seeing errors.

I had to update my global version of typescript so 'tsc' could run, but running npm install typescript@latest -g was also throwing errors. I had to remove the tsc link in /usr/bin/.

What I did to fix:

```
$ cd /usr/bin
$ sudo rm tsc
$ sudo npm install -g typescript@latest
```

Calling 'tsc' worked without errors after this.