# How do I include flex-layout?

Tags: angular, angular-flex-layout

I am trying to add flex-layout to an angular app, but when I do and try to use it the app breaks. I have installed

```
npm i @angular/flex-layout @angular/cdk
```

then imported in app.module.ts

```
import { FlexLayoutModule } from '@angular/flex-layout';

import [ FlexLayoutModule ]
```

I've also upgraded typescript to the latest

```
npm i typescript@latest
```

But when the app tries to compile, I get all kinds of errors:

```
ERROR in node_modules/@angular/flex-layout/core/typings/base/base2.d.ts:24:19 - error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.

24     protected get parentElement(): HTMLElement | null;
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular/flex-layout/core/typings/base/base2.d.ts:26:19 - error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.

26     protected get nativeElement(): HTMLElement;
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular/flex-layout/core/typings/base/base2.d.ts:28:9 - error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.

28     get activatedValue(): string;
       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular/flex-layout/core/typings/base/base2.d.ts:29:9 - error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.

29     set activatedValue(value: string);
       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular/flex-layout/core/typings/breakpoints/break-point-registry.d.ts:20:9 - error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.

20     get overlappings(): BreakPoint[];
       ~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular/flex-layout/core/typings/breakpoints/break-point-registry.d.ts:24:9 - error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
```

and the list goes on. Do I have a version mismatch of something?

Comment: or may be typescript version>

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59502139/ts1086-an-accessor-cannot-be-declared-in-an-ambient-context)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try to add tslib in dependencies

```
npm install --save tslib
```

**Edit**

If you are using Angular v8 then use v8 for flex-layout cause v9 need Angular v9.

Comment: Someone already raise issue for TS1086 error. [Loot at it and its solution](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/issues/1181#issuecomment-579023713). Answer is `v9 requires Angular v9 and more importantly TypeScript v3.7. Please use the v8 release of Flex Layout.`

Comment: That was it. Wrong version of Flex Layout.

Answer (score 27):

It's because you are on Angular 8 but the library required Angular 9. In your package.json use this version : `"@angular/flex-layout": "^8.0.0-beta.27"`

Answer (score 1):

1. Change version of flex-layout compatible with Angular 8. update angular.json

```
"@angular/flex-layout": "^8.0.0-beta.27"
```

2. install this update

```
npm install
```

To avoid this error
update tsconfig.json (Not recommended)

```
"compilerOptions": {
   "skipLibCheck":true
}
```