# ERROR in node_modules/ang-jsoneditor/jsoneditor/jsoneditor.component.d.ts(13,9)

Tags: angular, typescript, node-modules, jsoneditor

So, I am working on an angular project and 
recently I started to face this issue while running `npm start`. I am not facing the issue, if copy the older `node-modules` folder but only when I do a fresh `npm install`. 
I do not see any changes in my package.json file recently. But when I run `npm start`, I am getting this error: 
`ERROR in node_modules/ang-jsoneditor/jsoneditor/jsoneditor.component.d.ts(13,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.`

I tried to install the latest version of `typescript` but seems like that was not compatible with the angular-cli version I am using. Also, I tried to install the latest version of `jsoneditor` and `ang-jsoneditor`.

I am not sure if this is due to some version mismatch or due to some other error.

Here is a snippet of my `package.json`.

```
{
  "name": "Project",
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^7.2.12",
    "@angular/cdk": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "^7.2.12",
    "@angular/compiler": "^7.2.12",
    "@angular/core": "^7.2.12",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.11.0",
    "@angular/cli": "^7.3.8",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^7.2.12",
    "ang-jsoneditor": "^1.9.4",
    "jsoneditor": "^5.34.0",
    "typescript": "^3.2.4"
  }
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: May be a Typescript - Angular compatibility issue. Try replacing `"typescript": "^3.2.4"` with `"typescript": "~3.6.0"` (Note: `~` instead of `^`) and a fresh npm install.

Comment: @MichaelD If I use the typescript version <3.1~ and >3.3~, ```npm start``` throws error for typescript version compatibility. But I am using typescript version 3.2.4

Comment: Then please try replacing `^3.2.4` with `~3.2.4`.

Comment: @MichaelD Nope, It did not work. Still seeing the same error.

Comment: In that case, if possible, try updating the Angular CLI

Comment: @MichaelD still same after updating the Angular CLI

Comment: Then I am not exactly sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your version of the `ang-jsoneditor` package apparently [does not work](https://github.com/mariohmol/ang-jsoneditor/issues/65#issuecomment-624907030) with Angular 7 because it uses a higher version of TypeScript with a [breaking change](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59502221/12769288) which is causing the error. No official solution has been posted on the issue ticket yet but you can try to install an older version of `ang-jsoneditor` that is compatible with Angular 7.

Comment: This worked for me. Thank you. I downgraded the ```ang-jsoneditor``` version to 1.7.8.